# C# GetValue of PropertyInfo with SubClasses

Tags: c#, foreach, getproperty, getvalue

First of all, sorry for my bad English... I hope you'll understand what I want to say.

I have a problem with a little code where I need to get the value of class' properties. (That's not my full project, but the concept of what I want to do. And with this simple code, I'm blocked.)

There is the code: (This sample works correctly.)

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        test Group = new test();
        BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public |
                                    BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                    BindingFlags.Instance |
                                    BindingFlags.Static;
        Group.sub.a = "allo";
        Group.sub.b = "lol";

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in Group.GetType().GetField("sub").FieldType.GetProperties(bindingFlags))
        {
            string strName = property.Name;
            Console.WriteLine(strName + " = " + property.GetValue(Group.sub, null).ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("---------------");
        }
    }
}

public class test
{
    public test2 sub = new test2();
}

public class test2
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
}
```

But I want to replace `Group.sub` with a dynamic accessing (like the `foreach` with `GetField(Var)` where it works). I tried a lot of combinations, but I haven't found any solutions.

```
property.GetValue(property.DeclaringType, null)
```

or

```
property.GetValue(Group.GetType().GetField("sub"), null)
```

or

```
property.GetValue(Group.GetType().GetField("sub").FieldType, null)
```

So I think you understand. I would like to give the instance of object `Group.sub` dynamically. Because, on my full project, I have a lot of subclasses.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already accessing the `sub` field using `Group.GetType().GetField("sub")`, you'll need to get its value and hold on to it:

```
FieldInfo subField = Group.GetType().GetField("sub");

// get the value of the "sub" field of the current group
object subValue = subField.GetValue(Group);
foreach (PropertyInfo property in subField.FieldType.GetProperties(bindingFlags))
{
    string strName = property.Name;
    Console.WriteLine(strName + " = " + property.GetValue(subValue, null).ToString());    
}
```

Comment: Thank you C:Evenhuis for you response. It's exactly what i want to do !

I have tested and it works.

To do the same with an adding level, can we do like that ?


            FieldInfo subField = Group.GetType().GetField("sub");
            object subValue = subField.GetValue(Group);

            FieldInfo subField2 = Group.GetType().GetField("sub").FieldType.GetField("sub2");
            object subValue2 = subField2.GetValue(subValue);



Or a a faster way exists ?

Comment: Yeah you can, and you can "hold on" to previous results - ie. to get the "sub2" field info, you don't have to start at `Group.GetType()...`; you can use `subField.FieldType.GetField("sub2")`.

Comment: Thank you C.Evenhuis. I did it like that =)